# Why am I getting "property 'submitHandler' doesn't exist" error

Tags: javascript, react-native

When I run my app using ‘npx expo start --no-dev --minify’ it crashes with this error: Reference error: property ‘submitHandler’ doesn’t exist.

submitHandler function is declared in my AuthForm.js. The submitHandler declaration shows this error message when I hover on it: 'submitHandler' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)

I am calling submitHandler in the following states: isPasscodeEntry / isForgot / isLogin else is registration state.

here is the function:

```
if (isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword) {
        // Handle the submission for Passcode Entry screen
        onNewPassword({ passcode: enteredCode });
    } else {
        function submitHandler() { // has dull color indicates inactive code and shows error 'submitHandler' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)'
            onSubmit({
                email: enteredEmail,
                confirmEmail: enteredConfirmEmail,
                password: enteredPassword,
                confirmPassword: enteredConfirmPassword,
                passcode: enteredCode,
            });
        }
    }
```

I don't know why production and dev both show the same 'submitHandler' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133) error when I hover on submitHandler function but in dev the app starts and submitHandler works.

Here is the AuthForm component:

```
function AuthForm({ isLogin, isForgot, isPasscodeEntry, isNewPassword, setIsNewPassword, setIsPasscodeEntry, setIsForgot, onSubmit, credentialsInvalid, onNewPassword }) {
    const [enteredEmail, setEnteredEmail] = useState('');
    const [enteredConfirmEmail, setEnteredConfirmEmail] = useState('');
    const [enteredPassword, setEnteredPassword] = useState('');
    const [enteredConfirmPassword, setEnteredConfirmPassword] = useState('');
    const [enteredCode, setEnteredCode] = useState(''); // Added for passcode entry

    const {
        email: emailIsInvalid,
        confirmEmail: emailsDontMatch,
        password: passwordIsInvalid,
        confirmPassword: passwordsDontMatch,
    } = credentialsInvalid;

    function updateInputValueHandler(inputType, enteredValue) {
        switch (inputType) {
            case 'email':
                setEnteredEmail(enteredValue);
                break;
            case 'confirmEmail':
                setEnteredConfirmEmail(enteredValue);
                break;
            case 'password':
                setEnteredPassword(enteredValue);
                break;
            case 'confirmPassword':
                setEnteredConfirmPassword(enteredValue);
                break;
            case 'passcode':
                setEnteredCode(enteredValue);
                break;
        }
    }

    if (isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword) {
        // Handle the submission for Passcode Entry screen
        onNewPassword({ passcode: enteredCode });
    } else {
        function submitHandler() {
            onSubmit({
                email: enteredEmail,
                confirmEmail: enteredConfirmEmail,
                password: enteredPassword,
                confirmPassword: enteredConfirmPassword,
                passcode: enteredCode,
            });
        }
    }

    return (
        <KeyboardAvoidingView
            style={{ flex: 1 }}
            behavior={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 'padding' : 'height'}
            keyboardVerticalOffset={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? 0 : 100}
        >
            <View style={styles.form}>
                <View>
                    {/* // enter email to reset password */}
                    {isForgot && !isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword ? (
                        <Input
                            label="Email Address"
                            onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'email')}
                            value={enteredEmail}
                            textInputConfig={{
                                onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('email', text),
                                value: enteredEmail,
                            }}
                            keyboardType="email-address"
                            
                            isInvalid={emailIsInvalid}
                        />
                    ) : (
                        <>
                            {/* //Login or SignUp */}
                            {!isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword && (
                                <Input
                                    label="Email Address"
                                    onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'email')}
                                    value={enteredEmail}
                                    textInputConfig={{
                                        onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('email', text),
                                        value: enteredEmail,
                                    }}
                                    keyboardType="email-address"
                                    isInvalid={emailIsInvalid}
                                />
                            )}

                            {/* //onSignup */}
                            {!isLogin && !isForgot && !isNewPassword && (
                                <Input
                                    label="Confirm Email Address"
                                    onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'confirmEmail')}
                                    value={enteredConfirmEmail}
                                    keyboardType="email-address"
                                    isInvalid={emailsDontMatch}
                                />
                            )}

                            {/* // Login or Sign up */}
                            {!isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword && (
                                <Input
                                    label="Password"
                                    onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'password')}
                                    value={enteredPassword}
                                    textInputConfig={{
                                        onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('password', text),
                                        value: enteredPassword,
                                        secureTextEntry: true,
                                    }}
                                    isInvalid={passwordIsInvalid}
                                />
                            )}

                            {/* // onSignUp */}
                            {!isLogin && !isForgot && !isNewPassword && (
                                <Input
                                    label="Confirm Password"
                                    onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'confirmPassword')}
                                    value={enteredConfirmPassword}
                                    textInputConfig={{
                                        onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('confirmPassword', text),
                                        value: enteredConfirmPassword,
                                        secureTextEntry: true,
                                    }}
                                    isInvalid={passwordsDontMatch}
                                />
                            )}

                            {isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword && (
                                // Add your passcode entry component here
                                <>
                                    <Input
                                        label="Enter one-time passcode"
                                        onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'passcode')}
                                        value={enteredCode}
                                        textInputConfig={{
                                            onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('passcode', text),
                                            value: enteredCode,
                                        }}
                                    />
                                </>
                            )}

                            {/* Enter new password after correct OTP entered */}
                            {isNewPassword && (
                            <>
                                <Input
                                    label="Enter New Password"
                                        onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'password')}
                                        value={enteredPassword}
                                        textInputConfig={{
                                            onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('password', text),
                                            value: enteredPassword,
                                            secureTextEntry: true,
                                        }}
                                        isInvalid={passwordIsInvalid}
                                />

                                <Input
                                    label="Confirm New Password"
                                        onUpdateValue={updateInputValueHandler.bind(this, 'confirmPassword')}
                                        value={enteredConfirmPassword}
                                        textInputConfig={{
                                            onChangeText: (text) => updateInputValueHandler('confirmPassword', text),
                                            value: enteredConfirmPassword,
                                            secureTextEntry: true,
                                        }}
                                        isInvalid={passwordsDontMatch}
                                    />
                                </>
                            )}
                        </>
                    )}
                </View>
                <View style={styles.buttons}>
                    {isNewPassword && (
                        <Button onPress={() => { submitHandler(); }}>
                            Set New Password
                        </Button>
                    )}
                    {isPasscodeEntry && !isNewPassword ? (
                        <>
                            {/* // add to switch screen setIsNewPassword(); */}
                            <Button onPress={() => { submitHandler(); setIsNewPassword(); }}>
                                Submit Passcode
                            </Button>
                            <Text style={styles.label}>Enter the OTP passcode we sent to your email</Text>
                        </>
                    ) : (
                        isForgot && !isNewPassword && (
                            <Button onPress={() => { submitHandler(); setIsPasscodeEntry(); }}>
                                Reset Password
                            </Button>
                        )
                    )}
                    {!isPasscodeEntry && !isForgot && !isNewPassword && (
                        <Button onPress={submitHandler}>
                            {isLogin ? 'Log In' : 'Sign Up'}
                        </Button>
                    )}
                </View>



            </View>
        </KeyboardAvoidingView>
    );
}

export default AuthForm;
```

Strangely, or maybe not strange, when I run the app using only the command 'npx expo start' it runs exactly as expected: starts up to the login screen and I am able to login. it's only when I run the production mimic command 'npx expo start --no-dev --minify' that it crashes. I'm suspecting that this has to do with the conditional rendering of my JSX code based on the state isPasscodeEntry / isForgot / isLogin.

Comment: You define the function, but where do you actually call it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared submitHandler in your else part so its scope is in that else and you have not called "submitHandler" in else part so it is giving error of *"'submitHandler' is declared but its value is never read.ts(6133)"*.

You are calling your function from outside that scope thats why it can't be called.

To make it work, move your submitHandler outside of else, in main function.